# Opening a URL in using JavaScript in self window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript1.2">
function openwindow()
{
    window.open("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
}
</SCRIPT>
<P>
<A href="javascript: openwindow()">Open the JavaScript Window Example 1</A>
</P>
```

This is an example that opens a URL in new window. How can I make it open in same window? Something similar to `target=self`.

Answer (score 3):

simply use an Anchor for what it is for:

```
<A href="http://www.javascript-coder.com">Open the link</A>
```

no javascript needed ;)

however, the settings (menubar, scrollbars etc..) of the current window *cannot be changed* by javascript. THis is only possible in a *new* window on creation.

if you really need Javascript use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

```
 function openLink()
 {
     window.location.href = "http://www.javascript-coder.com";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript1.2">
   window.location.href="http://www.javascript-coder.com";
</SCRIPT>
```

This will assign the url to the current window's location. Something like self=target.